# When is ‘ae’ pronounced /ae/?

Tags: pronunciation, spelling, diphthong

I like the idea of using ligatures like ‘æ’ and ‘œ’ for diphthongs in Latin, so that the spelling is closer to one letter/character per sound. However, it would not work to write ‘æ’ for everything, because words like *aer* (also spelled *aër*) do not contain a diphthong but two different vowels.

Is there a list of such words?

Edit: Current list

- aer, a(h)eneus
- Greek names: Aerope
- Hebrew names: Israel, Michael, etc.

Comment: Would it be sufficient to have a dictionary that indicates whether the *ae* is a diphthong or not? Presumably you are using a dictionary to look up words anyway, so that'd be a natural place for such details.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Yes, this could work, but having a list would be helpful for me to know how many words are involved, are they common ones, is there any chance of just learning the list so as not to have to check the dictionary every time, etc.?

Comment: I can only think of **Israel** (Isrāēl)

Comment: @KotobaTrilyNgian There are a lot of such proper names: Michael, Aerope, etc.

Comment: @richardIII It's worth noting that *aer* was a transliterated borrowing from Greek ἀήρ: I'm curious now if there are native Latin words that have a dieresis.

Comment: @brianpck There are forms of *inchoare* and *boare/boere*, but the first seems to be a variation of *incohare* and the second seems to come from from *βοάω* (if it's not a cognate). These are not very satisfying contenders, so I'd be happy to see that as a separate question.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Those wouldn't count anyway since oa isn't a diphthong. There are plenty of Latin words where two vowels side by side do not form a diphthong.

Comment: @brianpck Does [aeneus](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic+letter%3DA%3Aentry+group%3D25%3Aentry%3Daeneus) count?

Comment: @cmw That's a great example! I notice that there is a spelling with h (ahen-), so perhaps that is what leads to such pronunciations.

Comment: @brianpck De Vaan has some interesting things to say about this, including that it might be an Umbrian loan or the -h- might be spurious. I'm no expert on this, though, so I can't weigh the options.

Comment: @cmw I meant that those verbs have inflected froms with an *oe* but no diphthong, such as *inchoes*. My point was just that verb inflection produces situations where one might want to use a dieresis to guide pronunciation.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Ah, gotcha. I wasn't thinking about endings.

Comment: For those that are interested in the pronunciation as vocalised, this is a nice video: [Latin AE: What's the right pronunciation?](https://youtu.be/PbYH5YJT0rI?si=m_BntspFj29vTWfd).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know of any such list, but they're almost exclusively foreign loans.

The only native Latin word I know of with a non-diphthong *ae* is *ahēneus* "bronze (adj)", also written ***aēneus***. Fortunately, in this case the long vowel can serve as a marking…or you can always write it with the *h*, if you like. The exact etymology of this word is unclear—De Vaan thinks it might be a loan from Umbrian—and it's possible that the *h* was inserted specifically for this reason, to mark that it's two syllables *aē* instead of one syllable *ae*. But it's almost certainly native Italic, given the connection with *aes*. (That would, as a side note, make it cognate with English "ore".)

Beyond that, there are plenty of loans from Greek (including loans from Greek that were originally from Aramaic and Hebrew) that transcribe αη as *aē*. Again here the length marker can serve as an indication that this isn't *ae*, but even books that don't mark vowel length consistently will generally write this as *aë* with a diaeresis. *Āēr* (ἀήρ) and *Michāēl* (Μιχαήλ) fall into this category.

Finally, there are a smaller number of loans from Greek that transcribe αε as *ae*. In this case, the length markers won't help you; in theory, you could write this as *aĕ*, but I don't know of anyone who does that. Instead, these words are practically universally written with a diaeresis, *aë*. *Aëropē* (Ἀερόπη) is one of these. I imagine there might be some of these from Hebrew or Aramaic as well, but the main cause of the non-diphthong *aē* in those names is the ending -ηλ, which universally has a long eta.

Overall, then, the standard solution to these issues is the diaeresis. It originated in Greek, where it's important to distinguish the diphthong αι from the non-diphthong αϊ. (These non-diphthongs were common in Homer and became steadily less so over time, eventually disappearing almost entirely: earlier Ἀΐδης became later ᾍδης.) In Latin it comes up pretty rarely, but when it does, it's important to have a way to indicate it.

Comment: I focused on ae here since that's the question in the title, but as pointed out in the comments, oe not being a diphthong is somewhat more common in native Latin words.