# What diphthongs are available are Unicode ligatures?

Tags: diphthong, paleography, ligatures

What diphthongs are available are Unicode ligatures?

I already know of æ (e.g., Romæ), œ (e.g., Œneus), and ꜷ (e.g., ꜷdire). Are there characters for the other diphthongs like ei, or eu.

See [When is ‘ae’ pronounced /ae/?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/23378/when-is-ae-pronounced-ae)

Comment: Please don't ever use ꜷ unless you're specifically transcribing a Medieval document that uses it. It's not meant to be used in normal text. The only reason æ and œ sometimes are is because they were read as simple vowels in Medieval and later Latin.

Comment: If you want to indicate a diphthong, there are other means than using ligatures. We might already have a question on that, and I'd welcome one if we don't. But do bear in mind that the best solution depends on your goal.

Comment: @Cairnarvon Why not? according to the Unicode standard, ꜷ is "LATIN SMALL LETTER AU", and æ is "LATIN SMALL LETTER AE", so I am not using a weird thing, and I don't think anyone would get mad

Comment: @richardIII LATIN in the Unicode standard means it's part of the Latin alphabet, as opposed to e.g. Arabic or Cyrillic. But that doesn't mean it's used for the Latin language. I don't think I've ever seen ꜷ used in a Latin text, ever.